# SBT dependecny GuiceApplicationBuilder

Tags: java, playframework, sbt, guice

How to specify play.api.inject.guice.GuiceApplicationBuilder dependency in SBT? I'm not able to get its dependency anywhere.

I want to use this to mock play framework Form in java. But I'm not able to get it imported as I'm not getting its dependency. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to specify unmanagedJars explicitly unless you have more complex configuration. Simply put your JAR files into the lib directory and they will be added to the classpath ([docs](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/tutorial/Library-Dependencies.html)).

To package an executable JAR with all the necessary dependencies use one of the SBT plugins: [sbt-onejar](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-onejar) or [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly/). package simply packages your classes into a jar and doesn't bother with including dependencies whatsoever.

The instructions in the docs of the plugins should be easy to guide you how to use them.

Comment: Thanks. When I tried to download the jar, I got the SBT dependency too. libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.play" % "play_2.11" % "2.4.0". I'm more comfortable with specifying dependencies is better than downloading adding the jars.